# Azure Sync not reflecting changes in on-premises database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-log-analytics

I have installed sync agent client on my local machine, and **configured the sync** between the azure SQL db and on-premises database.

In the Azure portal, I have set the sync timing to 5 minutes. and as of now, I am just syncing between one table.

In the sync logs, The details are : **Sync completed successfully in x.xx seconds.**

In the conflict resolution, I have set it to Member win. I tried with Hub win also and it is Bi-Directional sync.

Whenever i insert something in the table in Azure Db, after the sync, those changes are not reflected in the on-premises db.

Also, is there any way to check detailed logs of the Azure sync group?

Answer (score 1):

Please check and make sure that you've selected the columns/tables that you're inserting too for syncing.

Did you make any schema changes? These must be resolved manually.

Also please check to confirm that your local agent is online.
Best,
Josh

Comment: I have selected the columns, have not changed any schema and my local agent is online. Its state for that database is Reachable @Josh G

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on the Azure database (Hub) and see if it works:

```
ALTER DATABASE [database name]
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
```

Answer (score 0):

How many sync groups associating with the specific table?

Typically this issue is encountered while associating another sync group with the same table. If you use bi-directional sync, try to prevent other sync groups associate with the bi-directional table. If you did any changes or deleted records or tables from the `DataSync.table_dss_tracking` table, please delete the sync group and re-create it.